# Another card game probability calculation

Tags: probability, card-games, poker

The game:   dealer and multiple players,  lets say 6 players, 1 dealer.
Each participant received 2 cards.
Hands:  each hand consists of 4 cards,  the player's two cards and the dealer's two cards.

Goal:  Assuming fresh single deck, Calculate the probability that a given round contains the scope of typical poker and black jack hands  (one or more).  More specifically, what is the probability of one or more  single pairs, two pairs,  trips, 4 of a kind and blackjack.

Also, by one or more, I mean 1 exactly,  2 exactly etc as partitioned/separate calculations..

Basically, Im looking for a logic to try to properly frame the calculation, but certainly wont object to a detailed worked out response either.

Comment: So you're interested in the distribution of the number of valuable hands, not in the details of the types of hands? I.e., you want to know the probabilities for there being $1,2,\ldots$ valuable hands, but not e.g. the probability of there being one pair, one $4$ of a kind and one blackjack?

Comment: No, need to understand the details of the hands,  as i will end up trying to determine the expectation of the game, and each hand has different payout based upon the type of hand..

Comment: That's a whole lot of information you're looking for -- all the probabilities of all possible combinations of hands for $6$ players?

Comment: That's $\binom{12}6=924$ different probabilities -- you should just write a program to compute them -- no-one's going to work out and list a thousand probabilities here for you.

Comment: im really just looking for the structure of an example calculation... maybe i did not express myself..I am interested in the probability of say:  for 6 players..probability that there is exactly 1 hand with a pair,  exactly 2 hards with a pair,  exactly 1 hand has trips.. exactly 2 hands have trips.. etc..

Comment: In those examples, everyone has the same type of hands. That's a manageable number of probabilities. Where it becomes unmanageable is if you want all the combinations as well -- one triple and one pair, or two blackjacks and two pairs and one triple, or whatever -- if you restrict the question to counting the number of hands of a certain type, I'd try to answer it.

Comment: if I can see the structure of even a piece which addresses the multihand aspect, that will be new information for me and maybe I can extrapolate from there.. I have worked the single player #s fully, but having trouble moving to the multiplayer case..

Comment: If you are able to show me the probability calculation (I dont really care about the #, im really trying to understand the approach for it, which is why I am looking for the expression) for a single case, that would be helpful.  How about the probability, across 6 players, that that there is exactly 2 hands which each have exactly 2 pairs?

Comment: I'm working on it -- had other stuff to do today but will be posting a rather extensive answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll calculate the distributions for the numbers of hands with four of a kind, triple and two pairs. I'll leave the single pairs and blackjacks to you, since the calculation becomes rather involved.

Let $n$ denote the number of players. Let's start with four of a kind. This is easy – at most one player can have four of a kind, and the probability for a given player to have four of a kind is $\frac{13}{\binom{52}4}=\frac1{20825}$, so the probability of one of $n$ players to have four of a kind is $\frac n{20825}$.

Next, three of a kind. At most $2$ players can have three of a kind. There are two cases: the dealer has a pair, with probability $\frac3{51}=\frac1{17}$, or she doesn't. If she does, then by distributing the two remaining cards of that rank we find that the probability that exactly one player has exactly one matching card is

$$
2\cdot\frac{50-2n}{50}\cdot\frac{2n}{49}\;,
$$

and the probability that two players have exactly one matching card is

$$
\frac{2n}{50}\cdot\frac{2(n-1)}{49}\;.
$$

If she doesn't, at most two players can have a matching pair. The probability for a particular player to have a matching pair is

$$
p_1=\frac6{50}\cdot\frac2{49}\;,
$$

and the probability for two particular players to have a matching pair is

$$
p_2=\frac6{50}\cdot\frac2{49}\cdot\frac3{48}\cdot\frac2{47}\;,
$$

so the probability for exactly one player to have a matching pair is

$$
\binom n1p_1-2\binom n2p_2=\frac{6n}{1225}-\frac{3n(n-1)}{230300}
$$

and the probability for exactly two players to have a matching pair is

$$
\binom n2p_2=\frac{3n(n-1)}{460600}\;.
$$

Combining the results for the two cases, we find that overall the probability for exactly one player to have three of a kind is

$$
\frac1{17}\left(2\cdot\frac{50-2n}{50}\frac{2n}{49}+16\cdot\left(\frac{6n}{1225}-\frac{3n(n-1)}{230300}\right)\right)=\frac{8n(1153-25n)}{978775}\;,
$$

and for exactly two players,

$$
\frac1{17}\left(\frac{2n}{50}\frac{2(n-1)}{49}+16\cdot\frac{3n(n-1)}{460600}\right)=\frac{4n(n-1)}{39151}
\;.
$$

Finally, two pairs. Now any number of players can have two pairs. Again we can condition on whether the dealer has a pair.

If she does, we want the probability for exactly $m$ players to have a different pair. If $k$ players have such a pair, of which $j$ pairs of players have pairs of the same rank, then $k-2j$ players have pairs of a unique rank. There are $\frac{k!}{(k-2j)!2^j}$ ways to form the pairs of players, $\frac{12!}{(12-(k-j))!}$ ways to select ranks, $(4\cdot3)^{k-2j}$ ways to select the suits for the unique ranks and $(4\cdot3\cdot2)^j$ ways to select the suits for the paired ranks. Thus the probability for $k$ particular players to have a different pair than the dealer is

$$
\frac{(50-2k)!}{50!}\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac k2\right\rfloor}\frac{k!}{(k-2j)!}\frac{12!}{(12-(k-j))!}12^{k-j}\;,
$$

so by [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) the probability for exactly $m$ players to have a different pair is

$$
\sum_{k=m}^n(-1)^{k-m}\binom km\binom nk\frac{(50-2k)!}{50!}\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac k2\right\rfloor}\frac{k!}{(k-2j)!}\frac{12!}{(12-(k-j))!}12^{k-j}\;.
$$

If the dealer doesn't have a pair, up to $3$ players can match both of the dealer's ranks. The probabilities for $1$, $2$ or $3$ particular players to match both of the dealer's ranks are

\begin{align}
q_1&=\frac6{50}\cdot\frac3{49}\;,\\
q_2&=\frac4{48}\cdot\frac2{47}\cdot q_1\;,\\
q_3&=\frac2{46}\cdot\frac1{45}\cdot q_2\;,
\end{align}

and the probabilities for exactly $m$ players to match both of the dealer's ranks are

$$
\sum_{k=m}^3(-1)^{k-m}\binom km\binom nkq_k\;.
$$

If we define $q_k=0$ for $k\gt3$, we can combine these two results to get the total probability for exactly $m$ players to have two pairs:

$$
\frac1{17}\sum_{k=m}^n(-1)^{k-m}\binom km\binom nk\left(\frac{(50-2k)!}{50!}12!k!12^k\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac k2\right\rfloor}\frac1{(k-2j)!(12-(k-j))!12^j}+16q_k\right)\;.
$$

[Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/12ab6f10445baf50360a1268308944ac) that I used to check these results against simulations.

Comment: amazing....very nice...thank you very much..